# WordPress Widget Conflict

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a WordPress site soon to be launch and the theme developer is not responding anymore. Several users who bought the theme also have the same problem.

The calendar countdown plugin is conflicting with the theme design.

Here's the widget PHP code (events calendar section only):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('ABSPATH')) exit('restricted access');

//Feedburner_Widget Class

class FW_Eventcounter extends WP_Widget

{

    /** constructor */

    function __construct()

    {

        parent::__construct( /* Base ID */'eventcounter', /* Name */'Event Countdown', array( 'description' => 'Countdown the upcoming event' ) );

    }



    /** @see WP_Widget::widget */

    function widget($args, $instance)

    {

        global $_reserved_categories;



        $event_data = new wp_Query('showposts=4&meta_key=fw_event_time&meta_value='.time().'&meta_compare=>&order=asc&orderby=meta_value&post_type=events&post_status=publish');

        if( ! $event_data->found_posts) return;

        extract($args);

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        echo $before_widget;



        $first = true;

        $recent_events = '';

        ?>



        <div class="events">

        <?php

        if($event_data->have_posts())

        while($event_data->have_posts()): $event_data->the_post();



        $eventDATA = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'fw_events', true);

        $event_time = @get_time_difference(time(), $eventDATA['event_time']);

        $estartTime = @date('h:ia', $eventDATA['event_time']);

        $endTime = @date('h:ia', $eventDATA['event_time1']);



        foreach((array)$event_time as $k=>$v)

        {

            if(strlen($v) < 2) $event_time[$k] = (int) '0'.$event_time[$k];

        }



        $startTime = @implode(':', $event_time);



        if($first):

            $first = false;

            $title = ($startTime) ?  $title : 'Next Events';

            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;?>

            <?php if($startTime): ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function () {

                    var austDay = new Date(<?php echo date('Y',$eventDATA['event_time']);?>, <?php echo date('m',$eventDATA['event_time']);?> - 1, <?php echo date('d',$eventDATA['event_time']);?>);

                    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});

                });

            </script>

                <div class="countersec">

                    <div class="counters">

                        <div id="defaultCountdown"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="upcomingevent backcolr">

                        <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>" class="white"><?php the_title();?></a></h6>

                        <p><?php echo date('m/d/Y - h:i a', $eventDATA['event_time']);?>, <?php _e('Location:','heavens_corner');?> <?php echo $eventDATA['event_place'];?></p>

                    </div>

                </div>

            <?php endif;?>

        <?php else:

            $recent_events .= '<li>

                                <div class="datesec">

                                    <span class="date">'.date_i18n( 'd', $eventDATA['event_time'] ).'</span>

                                    <span class="month">'.date_i18n( 'M', $eventDATA['event_time'] ).'</span>

                                </div>

                                <div class="desc">

                                    <a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="txthover bold">'.get_the_title().'</a>

                                    <p>'.$estartTime.', '.__('Location:','heavens_corner').' '.$eventDATA['event_place'].'</p>

                                </div>

                            </li>';

        endif;?>

    <?php endwhile;?>

        <?php if($recent_events):?>

            <h3 class="colr bold widgethead"><?php _e('News and Events','heavens_corner');?></h3>

                <!-- Events Listing Start -->

                <ul><?php echo $recent_events;?></ul>

                <!-- Events Listing End -->

                <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'locations');?>

                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link((int)$terms[0]->term_id,'locations');?>" class="buttonone backcolr"><?php _e('View All','heavens_corner');?></a>

        <?php endif;?>

    </div>

    <?php

        echo $after_widget;

    }



    /** @see WP_Widget::update */

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance)

    {

        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);

        return $instance;

    }



    /** @see WP_Widget::form */

    function form($instance)

    {

        $title = ($instance) ? esc_attr($instance['title']) : 'Upcoming Event';

    ?>

        <p>

            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'heavens_corner'); ?></label> 

            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />

        </p>

    <?php 

    }



} // class event counter
```

Here is the demo site www.mbbcintl.com/wp/ the main page (mbbcintl.com) that has a problem is currently disabled for viewing but the theme came frome the mbbcintl.com/wp/ site that is working fine and I haven't done any modification just copy and paste the theme.

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get? I would check if `FW_Eventcounter` is declared multiple times.